# microsoft sql server: check users own permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL server database and a set of users.

Now in my app I want to make some functionality only visible, if the user has entered username and password with certain rights (admin).

Since the databases and the usernames and their rights can change, how do i check what permissions/rights an Microsoft SQL server user has?

Comment: Can you clarify - what kind of functionality should be visible depending on username//password? Do you store the username and password in your database, or do you mean it is a username/password under the sql server security folder? It sounds like you want to impliment your own security levels or a flag on your user table - User { Username, Password, isAdmin }, then in your app, when they login you can check are they an admin? If so so the extra functionality, if not, hide it. Also if you have many different levels of access, consider using a separate table

Comment: No i no additional functionality. To put it in simple terms. Imagine there are n user groups. Ther first can only query ther server. The second can query and perform insert statements. The third can also create views ... and so on. I actually just want to know what the current user is allowed to do in the database.

Comment: Btw. don't get fixated on groups. They don't need to be organized in groups. Just multiple users with different permissions. I just want to disable the functionality in the app, which the current dbuser can't use because he doesn't have the necessary permission on the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check current user's right on certain securables using `[sys.fn_mypermissions][1]` which returns all permission on the securable. You can also check a specific permission with [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx). Eg. you can check for `CONTROL SERVER` permission which implies an administrator is logged in:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'CONTROL SERVER');
```

Comment: Thanks, thats it. I now can check for example if the user has the insert right on a certain database:
SELECT  HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('databasename', 'DATABASE', 'INSERT') AS Expr1 . And also check other permissions according to the documentation link you included.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is using the **`IS_MEMBER('rolename')`** function, that checks whether the user is in the role/group **`'db_owner'`**. The function will perform a check at database level, and returns 1 (Int32), if the user has the specified role.

If you need to check at server level, you can use the IS_SRVROLEMEMBER function. Both are available since SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain that I understand your problem definition however assuming I do.....

I would suggest that you create a SQL Server Database Role that you can add the relevant application users to, perhaps via some group membership maintained within the App (or a Windows Domain Group). You can use the group to Role mapping to independently manage user membership, from managing the relevant permissions to securables within the database via the Role.

This way, you just need to check that an application User is a member of the relevant application or windows group, without the need to query the security configuration of SQL Server.

Comment: From a design perspective I still don't see why you need to "check" permissions. Permissions are granted by means of membership to the appropriate Role, to which the user authentication you have in place validates. Simply create a Role with the required "admin" rights and a Role with the required user rights. Then add/map the users to the relevant roles. You would then not need to check/validate permissions because the fact the user can login with the correct credentials serves this purpose.